# Codenameone I want to display html inside a TextArea

Tags: codenameone

I just want to display html text inside a textArea for exemple if I write `<h1>Header</h1>` I want it to be displayed as header not with the tags.
I tried with webBrowser but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codename Ones text area doesn't support it. What you're looking for is a rich text edit which we don't have. What you can do is use the `BrowserComponent` and in it open an HTML rich edit and use that.

There used to be a CN1LIB that did that seamlessly but because JS frameworks break constantly it stopped working.